# How can I pass events on to a hidden <browser>?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, xul, xulrunner

I've working on a simple view around a browser using XULRunner 1.9.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/"?>
<window
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <hbox equalsize="always" flex="2">
    <browser flex="1" type="content-primary"/>
    <html:canvas flex="1"/>
  </hbox>
</window>
```

I've written some Javascript that handles `MozAfterPaint` events from the `<browser>`, pushes them to the `<canvas>` with `drawWindow`, and then does some magic.  It all works fairly nicely.  (Well, scrollbars and cursors are kinda wonky, but I can ignore those.)

I really want the canvas to be the only visible element, but I can only interact with the browser element right now.

What I've had partial success with:

- Capture events on the `<canvas>` and re-inject them into the `<browser>`.

  I can use the `clientX` and `clientY` of each event to the canvas, look up the corresponding `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` in the browser, and `createEvent` `initEvent` `dispatchEvent` appropriately.

  However, this only works well for `key(down/press/up)`, `click`, and `mouse(down/move/up)`.  I don't see how to reasonably synthesize `mouse(over/out)` events, and `DOMMouseScroll` doesn't fire here so I can't capture scroll wheel events.

What I've had no success with:

- Stacking the canvas above the browser.

  ```
  <stack flex="2">
    <browser flex="1" type="content-primary"/>
    <html:canvas flex="1"/>
  </stack>
  ```

  This requires some way of allowing events to pass through the canvas and onto the browser instead, which I haven't really tried yet, because there's a more immediate problem:

  Even though the canvas **should** be stacked above the browser, the browser is visible above the canvas.
- Stack the browser above the canvas while making it transparent.

  ```
  <stack flex="2">
    <html:canvas flex="1"/>
    <browser flex="1" type="content-primary" style="opacity: 0;"/>
  </stack>
  ```

  In theory, I shouldn't have to mess with events at all this way.  However, the `opacity` setting doesn't seem to do any good, and again, the browser still occludes the canvas.

How do I hide the browser yet still allow normal interaction with it?

---

(I'm not adverse to writing native code, and WebKit answers are fine too.  But as far as I can tell, neither Gecko nor WebKit have off-screen rendering APIs, and there's no WebKit equivalents to `MozAfterPaint` and `drawWindow`.)

Answer (score 0):

As I recall you can do this by using [`mousethrough="always"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/mousethrough) attribute but I'm not sure that you can set it directly on the `<canvas>` element itself, so you may need to wrap it inside some sort of box. Otherwise as you're using XULRunner 1.9.2 I believe the [pointer-events: none;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property can be used instead.