# Unable to access panel from script

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

In my browser.xul file I have a panel element:

```
<panel id="panel1">
   <!-- Elements -->
</panel>
```

When I try:

```
window.document.getElementById("panel1").openPopup(button, "after_start", 0, 0, false, false);
```

the browser says that:

```
window.document.getElementById("panel1") is null.
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I got the answer. Actually I was creating a new panel inside overlay. Basically, overlay is meant to override something. So, it just ignores it when there is something is new. so, I added it into already existing box element. It works fine!

Comment: Yes, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391635/firefox-addons-hidden-browser-in-xul-overlay/7491047#7491047

Answer (score 0):

it's my first time I see panel tag in html..

are you sure you don't mean :

```
<div id="panel1">
....
</div>
```

Comment: This is in a Firefox extension. `panel` is a XUL element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel